# AngularJS - Something wrong in htaccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

I have an AngularJS webapp. 
When I build my project and upload to server (with htaccess), getting this error:

```
Internal Server Error
```

But when I remove htaccess file, its works fine. But this time, when I want to go inside pages, getting 404.

Whats the problem?

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css¦js|html|png) #Add extra extensions needed.
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: You need to setup server to *always* respond with `index` page so that angular could bootstrap application and process routing.